# $ajax and jQuery send data to php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send data with jQuery and Ajax using $.ajax. I simplified the case just to send one thing but it does not work. Can someone help?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="button">clic!</a>
<br>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        name: "John",
        type: 'POST',
        url:"3.php",
        success:function(result){
            $("#content").html(result);
        }
    });

 });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo $name;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should send data like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "3.php",
    data: { name: "John" },
    success:function(result){
        $("#content").html(result);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery syntax is wrong. You should add `data` field and put postvars there:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "3.php",
   data: { name: "John" }
   success:function(result){
       $("#content").html(result);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending wrong  `name: "John",`it will be `data: { name: "John" }`  then you will get`$_REQUEST['name']` on php page
so full request will be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "3.php",
    data: { name: "John" },
    success:function(result){
        $("#content").html(result);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"3.php",
        data:{name:"John"},
        success:function(result){
            $("#content").html(result);
        }
    });

 });
```